# Extract text in sub-element based on another sub-element text in the same level

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm new to XML and I have been thinking about this question for a long time...I want to extract text contents from the element based on another text content in another element with the same name at the same level from xml file with python:

This is how xml looks like:

```
<element2>
<source> content1 </source>
<ref> content2 </ref>
</element2>

<element2>
<source> content3 </source>
<ref> content4 </ref>
</element2>

<element2>
....
</element2>
.
.
.
```

I want to extract text "content2" based on the text "content1". Yet if I used iter() or child.tag, I can't precisely locate the text I want to extract. Even child.find(content2) does not work because there are multiple "element2" and it only extract the first element2 it finds, but I am interested in extracting any content in `<ref>` based on text content in `<source>`. I wonder if there's any suggested way to extract the text like dictionary? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to extract each `source`/`ref` pair of values contained in an `element2` wrapper into a list of dictionaries you can use

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
<element2>
<source> content1 </source>
<ref> content2 </ref>
</element2>

<element2>
<source> content3 </source>
<ref> content4 </ref>
</element2>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

result = [ { 'source' : element2.find('source').text, 'ref' : element2.find('ref').text } for element2 in root.findall('.//element2')]

print(result)
```

So that way you get a result like

```
[{'source': ' content1 ', 'ref': ' content2 '}, {'source': ' content3 ', 'ref': ' content4 '}]
```